# Is it possible to customize CNContactPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactpicker

I am new to iOS development and was wondering if I can modify `CNContactPickerViewController` `tableViewCell` such that the contacts who are already using my app are shown in somewhat a different way.

And add an invite button to the contacts who are not using my app.

Is using `CNContactPickerViewController` even the right approach?

Thanks!